# PostGIS: incorrect interpretation of a polygon that intersects the 180th meridian

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I try to find out all geopoints which intersect the polygon set as a parameter.

The problem is when I pass polygon that roughly covers an area of Bering Strait (nearby 180 longitude):
[image]

So I use the query:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(l.geo_point)
FROM "lightnings" "l"
WHERE (ST_Intersects(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((132.0 40.0, -148.0 40.0, -148.0 -8.0, 132.0 -8.0, 132.0 40.0) )', 4326), geo_point));
```

As you can see, vertexes are set in a correct order, clockwise, from the North-West. But the result covers outside area and including whole other world.

For example, in result:

```
POINT(75.5637 40.0434)
```

The problem doesn't touch the 0th meridian.

Elementary test:

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((0.0 60.0, 10.0 60.0, 10.0 40.0, 0.0 40.0, 0.0 60.0) )', 4326))
UNION ALL
SELECT ST_Area(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((-5.0 60.0, 5.0 60.0, 5.0 40.0, -5.0 40.0, -5.0 60.0) )', 4326))
UNION ALL
SELECT ST_Area(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((175.0 60.0, -175.0 60.0, -175.0 40.0, 175.0 40.0, 175.0 60.0) )', 4326))
```

gives the result:

```
200
200
7000
```

Is there any simple trick to force PostGIS understanding me? I don't like an idea to divide the polygon...

Answer (score 5):

PostGIS has a built in function ST_ShiftLongitude(geom) to return Lon/Lat geometries as 0-360 degrees instead of -180 - 180.

Wrap your polygons in this, and the resulting area calculations should be OK.

Description [here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Shift_Longitude.html)

BTW, I guess you realize that your ST_Area calculation is giving square degrees. Not really useful... If you use the new Geography data type, (ST_GeographyFrom Text(...) ) then the Area calculation will be in meters.

*Addition:*

Here's what I get

```
geodata=# SELECT ST_Area(
   ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON((
   -179.5 0, 179.5 0, 179.5 1, -179.5 1, -179.5 0))')
   );

 st_area 
---------
     359
(1 row)

geodata=# SELECT ST_Area(
   ST_ShiftLongitude(
   ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON((
   -179.5 0, 179.5 0, 179.5 1, -179.5 1, -179.5 0))')));

 st_area 
---------
       1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks! Of course I see what ST_Area means in this projection :) That's just for obviousness of PostGIS logic.

Comment: Good function. But the result of test is almost the same, but wrong for the other meridian: `200, 700, 200`

Comment: I've added a sample to the Answer above. Using ST_Shift_Longitude() returns the correct area for a polygon crossing the -180 deg boundary.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but this situation is human-controlled. I gave to work with polygons generated by Google Maps - on the whole world. So ST_SHIFT_Longitude helps with the 180th meridian but plunge into the same troubles with the 0th meridian. Just try `SELECT ST_Area(ST_Shift_Longitude(ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((-5.0 60.0, 5.0 60.0, 5.0 40.0, -5.0 40.0, -5.0 60.0))', 4326)))`

Comment: The only way I can think to work this out is make a line feature at the '180' meridian. Now create a function to test for each polygon if it intersects that line. If yes, then use the ST_Shift_longitude, otherwise the regular ST_Area. HTH

Answer (score 1):

I asked and answered a similar question here: [The minimum bounding circle of geometry that crosses the 180th meridian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19167/the-minimum-bounding-circle-of-geometry-that-crosses-the-180th-meridian)

What you can do (though this may be even more ugly than dividing the polygon) is use values over 180/-180.  E.g. rather than having polygon((179, 0), (-179, 0)), you can use polygon((179, 0), (181, 0)).  The question I linked to has a python script that shifts whole polygons like this.  You could adapt it to shift vertexes within your polygon.